# In vscode, font size of code completion is too small

Tags: visual-studio-code

I reinstall my vscode, and delete all settings in `setting.json`, but don't work.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `settings.json` play around with below value to change the fontsize.

```
"editor.suggestFontSize": 16
```

Comment: sad, it doesn't work

Comment: Well, you deleted all settings, perhaps you could get a default `settings.json` and retry.

Comment: Also, did you do this already? @LiWenchi https://techstacker.com/change-vscode-settings-ui-to-settings-json/#:~:text=json%20file%3A,change%20it%20to%20%E2%80%9Cjson%E2%80%9D.

Comment: Thanks anyway, the article you forwarded reminded me that I deleted all relevant configuration files in the C drive. Including Delete `%APPDATA%\Code` and `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode`, and other folders whose names appear to be related to it. In the end I reinstalled vscode and everything was back as it was, It's a pity that all extensions need to be reinstalled.

Comment: Very embarrassing, I finally found out that the file `.vscode/setting.json` in the project was overriding the global setting, and I finally deleted that file.

Comment: Happens to the best of us :). Glad you got it working, 'cause that small font seems really annoying.